# mysql - current_timestamp and null

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I have question about mysql configuration. 
I have the same database on AWS and local apache server on ubuntu.

In my table I have column type `timestamp` with `current_timestamp` and when  I trying to add new row with NULL on my local server it works fine and puting current date, but when I trying the same on AWS then I see error with information that column should not be `null`.
I want to change my local server configuration to the same like AWS. Maybe somebody knows where I can do this?

Comment: I bet the 2 servers are running DIFFERENT versions of MySQL

Comment: Read about `SQL_MODE` variable and `NO_ZERO_IN_DATE` and `NO_ZERO_DATE`. Check your settings.